# One extra row in a sum column query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building the following query:

```
SELECT taskid
FROM tasks, (SELECT @var_sum := 0) a
WHERE (@var_sum := @var_sum + taskid) < 10
```

Result:

```
taskid
1
2
3
```

Right now it's returning me all rows that when summed are <10, I want to include one extra row to my result (10 can be anything though, it's just an example value)

So, desired result:

```
taskid
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: use `<=` instead of `<` ? as 6+ 4... = 10 (oh yeah)

Comment: That works for 10, but not for 5 - for example.

Comment: Oh, seems you should explain better what you want...

Comment: I've edited my question, it can be any value, not restricted to 10 at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT t.taskid
  FROM tasks t 
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT @var_sum := 0) a
 WHERE IF(@var_sum<10, @var_sum := @var_sum+t.taskid, @var_sum := NULL) IS NOT NULL
```

This is checking if the current value of `@var_sum` is less than 10 (or less than whatever, or less than or equal to whatever. If it is, we add the taskid value to @var_num, and the row is included in the resultset. But when the current value of @var_sum doesn't meet the condition, we assign a NULL to it, and the row does not get included.

**NOTE** The order of rows returned from the `tasks` table is not guaranteed. MySQL can return the rows in any order; it may look deterministic in your testing, but that's likely because MySQL is choosing the same access plan against the same data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first value that is ">= 10":

```
SELECT taskid
FROM tasks, (SELECT @var_sum := 0) a
WHERE (@var_sum < 10) or (@var_sum < 10 and @var_sum := @var_sum + taskid) >= 10);
```

Although this will (probably) work in practice, I don't think it is guaranteed to work.  MySQL does not specify the order of evaluation for `where` clauses.

EDIT:

This should work:

```
select taskid
from (SELECT taskid, (@var_sum := @var_sum + taskid) as varsum
      FROM tasks t cross join
           (SELECT @var_sum := 0) const
    ) t
WHERE (varsum < 10) or (varsum - taskid < 10 and varsum >= 10);
```

Comment: First query only returns that one row. Second query - Unknown column 'var_sum' in 'where clause'

Comment: @JoaoFerreira . . . Fixed the problem.  When faced with this problem, I usually just want the first row that achieves a particular value, not all the values that lead up to it.

Comment: Your query is now returning me a SQL syntax error LIMIT 0, 50' at line 3, I have limited SQL experience, but can't figure out why, the logic makes sense to me now though.

Comment: It was the last ) in the query. Still, that query returns me all rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

To add an extra row use `UNION ALL` then code what you want for the extra row:

```
SELECT taskid
FROM tasks, (SELECT @var_sum := 0) a
WHERE (@var_sum := @var_sum + taskid) < 10
UNION ALL
SELECT 4
```

Because you haven't said how you derive the extra riw, I have coded a constant value, but you can change it to whatever you need.